# Install MongoDB driver in Cent os 7 with php7.1

Tags: php, mongodb, centos7, php-7.1

I have `Centos 7` and `php 7.1`. I want to install `pecl` and I tried that with `yum install pecl` but it has a conflict with `php5.4`. 
How can I install mongodb driver without `pecl` or how can I fix `pecl` to work with `php7.1`?

Comment: IMHO, it's never a good idea to use or risk overwriting system installs or really "root install" any runtime environment. You should avoid conflicts and manage different environments with something like [phpbrew](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew) or [phpenv](https://github.com/phpenv/phpenv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Install mongodb manually with following commands:
First install `php71w-devel` package with following command:

```
sudo yum install php71w-devel -y
```

and then you can install it manually.

> ```
> $ git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver.git
> $ cd mongo-php-driver
> $ git submodule sync && git submodule update --init
> $ phpize
> $ ./configure
> $ make all -j 5
> $ sudo make install
> ```
>
> ref:http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.manual.php

Answer (score 9):

I used pecl to install the mongo driver.

```
yum install php-pear
pecl install mongodb
```

note that there's also an old `mongo` driver that works for php5 but `mongodb` driver is for php7